# Java Application Correctly Referencing 3rd Party Libraries in Windows 7 But Not In Windows 2008 Server

Tags: java, windows-7

I have developed a Java application that references a third party library. Let's call it SW_Lib and the sub folder containing relevant DLL and Lib files SW_Lib\lib.

The application works fine on Windows 7 Professional. I have used Windows 7 Professional for development and testing.

I wish to run the application in production on a Windows 2008 Server Standard (64 bit) operating system.  And this is where I am encountering problems. While the application compiles fine, it complains at run time due to its inability to dynamically link the SW_Lib libraries.

In Windows 7 workstations, I have set the Path environment variable correctly to reference SW_Lib libraries. For my example, it simply says C:\Java\SW_Lib\lib. This works perfectly in the Windows 7 workstations.

In the Windows 2008 Server, I set the Path environment variable in exactly the same way and made sure that all directory structures are the same in both Windows 7 and Windows 2008 Server.

But my application simply cannot reference a particular DLL in SW_Lib\lib folder at run time in the server. I have looked at the internet for clues and it seems that setting the Path environment variable correctly should prevent me from having this issue, except that this is currently not working in Windows 2008 server.

I am using JDK 1.8 and am wondering if there are any backward compatibility issues with that and Windows 2008 Server. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about native libraries or jars?

If native libraries, have you checked java.library.path System property in both environments?

Are both environments running same 32/64 bit architecture?

Comment: Native libraries. I have checked the java.library.path using System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")) in the code. In both machines, I can see C:\Java\SW_Lib\lib included. Both environments have 64 bit architecture.